# How can I tell why my PC hasn't upgraded to Windows 10 build 1809?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1809

I have Windows 10 version 1803, as revealed by running Winver, and the Windows Updates page shows that there are no updates available.

I am aware of the problems MS had with build 1809 on its initial release and that certain machines are still blocked using the Upgrade Block functionality.

However, none of [the outstanding upgrade blocks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464619/windows-10-update-history) applies to me.

I'm running Windows 10 Home edition. The machine is four years old, Core i3 with 8 gigs of ram and lots of disk space.

Is there a way to find out why 1809 still isn't being offered?

Comment: Have you confirmed your update settings are not set to delay or pause updates for a period of time? Feature updates, like v1809 can be delayed for several months in your update settings if you’re running Win 10 Pro or Enterprise. You can also put your PC on the “slow” track, known as semi-annual or “business” channel. Which delays updates also.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, I'm running Windows 10 Home so I don't think I have the ability to choose delays and so-on.

Comment: Do you have  Intel display drivers versions 24.20.100.6344 and 24.20.100.6345? ....https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/devices-with-intel-audio-display-drivers-may-lose/e6b71763-5d32-4341-b4fc-43603c64ac47?tm=1542828490973&auth=1

Comment: No, I'm running version 20.19.15.4835.